# Cococs2dx: CCCallFuncN pSelectorTarget

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm new with cocos2d-x and maybe this is a stupid question.

Here my code:
In init() of Helloworld:

```
CCSprite *pSprite1 = new CCSprite();
pSprite1 = CCSprite::create("Icon-72.png");
pSprite1->cocos2d::CCNode::setPosition(200, 200);
this->addChild(pSprite1);

CCSprite *pSprite2 = new CCSprite();
pSprite2 = CCSprite::create("Icon-72.png");
pSprite2->cocos2d::CCNode::setPosition(900, 500);
this->addChild(pSprite2);

CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
CCMoveTo *move = CCMoveTo::create(1.0f, ccp(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
CCCallFuncN *callFuncN = CCCallFuncN::create(pSprite2, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc));
pSprite1->runAction(CCSequence::create(move, callFuncN, NULL));
```

this is testCCCallFunc:

```
void HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc(cocos2d::CCSprite *sender) {
sender->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);}
```

All i want is when the pSprite1 move finish, the pSprite2 will be removed. But in real pSprite1 removed and pSprite2 still on the screen.

I have try replace

```
CCCallFuncN::create(pSprite1, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc));
```

with

```
CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc));
```

or even this

```
CCCallFuncN::create(NULL, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc));
```

all code above run fine but i cant remove pSprite2, what i do worng?, What exactly CCObject *pSelectorTarget use for?

PS:sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should remove `new CCSprite();` while declaring, because you used `create` function, which would be auto-release. But you did not write `release()` for `new`, while would lead memory leak.

Then let us back to your question.

From the .h file, `static CCCallFuncN * create(CCObject* pSelectorTarget, SEL_CallFuncN selector);` has two argument.

The first one, is the object that will execute `selector` method. So in your case, here should be `this`(the instance of `HelloWorld`).

In  `void HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc(cocos2d::CCSprite *sender)`, this `sender` is actually **the object that run action**, that's why your `pSprite1` was removed.

You can check the source code of `CCCallFuncN::execute()` and `CCActionManager::addAction()` for detail.

The last, to achieve what you want, you can use `CCCallFuncO`.

```
CCCallFuncO *callFuncO = CCCallFuncO::create(this, callfuncO_selector(HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc), pSprite2);
pSprite1->runAction(CCSequence::create(move, callFuncO, NULL));
```

and

```
void HelloWorld::testCCCallFunc(cocos2d::CCSprite *object) {
  object->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
}
```